# Bijection of $L^2$ functions $(-\infty,\infty)$to the positive half line

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose we have the Hilbert space, $U_1$, of real valued functions $f(x) \in L^2(-\infty,\infty)$. I would like to create a bijection that preserves the Hilbert space structure and sends $f(x)$ to another Hilbert space $U_2$, with functions $g(x)$ valid on $[0,\infty)$, with specific interest in the value of $g(0)$.

I apologize if this notation is not correct (it is part of the reason for my question)

My thought was to use the following mapping: for functions $f(x) \in U_1$, create a map that sends x to $e^x$, and then the inverse sends x to $\log(x)$ for functions $g(x)\in U_2$.

1. is the correct notation for this mapping:
   $$ b:x\to e^x, f(x)\in U_1$$
   $$b^{-1}:x\to \log(x), g(x)\in U_2$$
2. Under this mapping, is the correct domain for $g(x)\in U_2$,  $[0,\infty)$ or $(0,\infty)$, and does this mapping preserve the Hilbert space structure?
3. I would like $g(0)=0$ for all functions in $U_2$. I understand that the functions in $U_1$ are $L^2$ so are equal a.e. (meaning there could be points of measure zero out to $-\infty$ where $f(x)\neq 0$). would it be more sensible to work with the Hilbert space $L^2\cup C_0$ of continuous functions that are also $L^2?

I apologize if this question is poorly stated or trivial... i have an Numerical methods background but have found myself working on a project that needs more mathematical rigor.

Comment: What do you mean by "preserving Hilbert structure"? You can always equip $(0,\infty)$ with a measure that is compatible with your proposed mapping.

Comment: sorry. i just meant that i would also like $U_2$ to be a Hilbert space.

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)|^2dx=\int_0^\infty |f(\log y)|^2\frac{dy}y$ so the obvious isomorphism $L^2(\Bbb{R})\to L^2(\Bbb{R}_{> 0})$ is $f\to \frac{f(\log y)}{y^{1/2}}$.